# How to access a page on my local server outside my android hotspot

Tags: java, android, ip, port, portforwarding

I have a JEE application running on apache server over port 8080 on my laptop.

My laptop is connected to internet via android hotspot, port 8080 is not blocked by firewall on my laptop.

How can I access a page from my server through a device outside my hotspot?

IPConfig on my laptop:

```
ipv4:  192.168.43.95
default gateway: 192.168.43.1
```

I tried to use port forwarder app on my phone to configure port forwarding from port 8080 to IP 192.168.43.95 : port 8080

Port forwarder displayed my device(android) as 100.85.254.126.

My public IP on my laptop is 101.222.171.254 (checked by typing 'what is my ip' on google) and this ip is same for android device serving the hotspot (sure the android device is acting as router).

I need to access pages on my server over internet (from device not in my hotspot), 
I tried accessing pages on my server over 100.85.254.126:8080 and 101.222.171.254:8080, I receive connection timed out in both the cases.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: So your device has both a public ip AND it is wirelessly connected to an Android device? And where is that other Android device? You did tell nothing of that. And how do you want to connect that last device to your laptop? Using which ip? It's all very vague what you want.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, my laptop is running a server instance and my laptop is connected to internet via hotspot of my android device. I need to access pages on the server over internet (from a device not connected to my hotspot).

Comment: `(from a device not connected to my hotspot).` You place that between brackets as if it is not important. Where is that device?

Comment: `my laptop is connected to internet via hotspot of my android device.`. For that your android device has to be connected to the internet. Lets assume it has a mobile connection. For the other device -the one you did not tell where it was but lets assume it's somewhere on the internet-.to connect through the android hotspot to your server on your laptop, your android device has to forward the used port to your laptop. But even if you succeed the whole setup will not work as your mobile provider most certainly will not allow servers running on your hotspot.

Comment: @greenapps Android device is connected to internet and device trying to access can be anywhere in internet. I previously used a dial up (from a S60 device) connection but android does not support dial up connections. 'code'  I tried to use port forwarder app on my phone to configure port forwarding from port 8080 to IP 192.168.43.95 : port 8080 'code' as I mentioned it is not working. Am I missing something.

Comment: 'Am I missing something. '. Yes. You are not reacting on what i said about your mobile provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think tou will need to forward your port 8080 on your router.
I'm not sure.

Comment: That is my guess too, I am not sure to which IP I should forward to. (As I am using android device;'s hotspot, it will act as router).

Comment: If possible you should forward to the ip your laptop got from your hotspot.